# Connect Angular Project to Docker BE

Tags: angular, docker

Is it possible to connect Angular project that is ran natively from bash
to the
Docker BE container?
I have Angular project configured as a part of Docker container, but working like this is painful because Angular rebuilds very slow at any changes (Windows 10). That's why I want to run Angular project separately aside from Docker.
In Docker I have Maven BE and PostgreSql DB, keycloak

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to connect Angular project that is ran natively from bash to the Docker BE container?

**Yes, it is possible** to connect Angular project that is ran natively from bash to the Docker BE container.

You need to configure the backend service URLs in your Angular project.  I usually do it using environment configuration files.

For example `environment.ts` for development:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  apiUrl: 'http://localhost:your-backend-port', // Don't forget to use the IP address or hostname of your Docker container
};
```

Then you need to run the Angular project locally using the Angular CLI, and consider setting up a proxy configuration for CORS if needed.

That is it. I hope it will help you.

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you advise me where should I configure proxy (Windows or angular.json or maybe somewhere in BE?) or with what software (if Windows) as the best solution?

Comment: @E_someRandomString You can set the API base URL in an environment configuration file or directly in your services. I updated the answer, you can check this environment.ts example now.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll check it in a couple of minutes :D

Comment: Ok still problem comes because of CORS. I think I'd have to run Angular under specific url than localhost:4200, but as I've tried few times, I didn't know how to configure Apache on Windows to do that =/

Comment: @E_someRandomString To resolve the CORS problem you can set up a reverse proxy using Apache on Windows.

Comment: yes I know, but like I wrote, I have tried many times do configure it and always failed :( Maybe some other softs?